# Clone list item using Lists Web Service & REST in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, list, rest, web-services

I know how to add/edit/delete items in a list using Lists Web Service (lists.asmx) and REST but I'm wondering if there is an easy way to clone? I know I can get the item, iterate through its data and create a new list item with the same data but that seems complicated and thought there might be a faster/easier way?

Comment: In the past, I just created a workflow to do it, then used jQuery to call the workflow to clone the item, example of starting a workflow, http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=StartWorkflow&referringTitle=Workflow

Comment: this is for a JavaScript tool I am writing (nsptiles.js.org) so I can't create a workflow. hoping for a pure JS solution.